# Llamar dinamicamente un metodo dentro de una clase

Tags: php, laravel-5

¿es posible llamar a métodos de forma dinámica en PHP?

Dentro de una clase quiere tener distintos métodos con un patron

```
class MyClass 
{

    private $tables;

    function __construct(){
        $this->tables = array('a','b','n');
    }

    public function runMigrations() {
        foreach ($this->tables as $table) {
            // Excecute method migration_$table)
            call_user_func('migration_'.$table.'()');  // Try but not work  
            // call_user_func('this->migration_'.$table.'()');;  // Try but not work  
            // call_user_func('$this->migration_'.$table.'()');
        }
    }

    private function migration_a() {
        // Some code
    }

    ..

    private function migration_n() {
        // Some code
    }

}



[ErrorException]                                                                                                                
  call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'migration_a()' not found or invalid function name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque la pregunta la realice para hacer el código con `call_user_func`, la verdad es que ni es necesario, ni creo que sea una buena practica.

La solución es mas sencilla:

```
$this->{'migration_'.$table}();
```

Con `call_user_func` sería:

```
call_user_func([$this, 'migration_'.$table]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes llamar la función de la siguiente forma:

```
call_user_func(array($this, 'metodo'));
```

Con la posición 0 del array le indicas que es el objeto actual

Saludos

Comment: Gracias. Encontre la forma, sin usar call_user_func, que creo es mas apropiada. Ademas creo que le falta algo a ese codigo,.me dio fallo. call_user_func(array_add($this,'migration_'.$table)); ->> Missing argument 3 for array_add(),

Answer (score 0):

Aquí el problema que se presenta al llamar a las funciones de forma no estática, es *que en algún momento podría pasar que se llamase a un método que no exista*.

No obstante el primer error es crear un array de esta forma:

```
$this->tables = ('a','b','n');
```

Lo ideal es hacerlo así:

```
$this->tables = array('a','b','n', 'z'); // <------- mejor así !
$this->tables = ['a','b','n', 'z'];       // <------- o así !
```

La forma rápida:

```
class MyClass1
{
    private $tables;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->tables = array('a', 'b', 'n', 'z');
    }

    /**
     * Lo rápido
     * Pero si no existe el método lanza un error:
     * Fatal error: Call to undefined method MyClass::migration_z() in //...
     */
    public function runMigrations1()
    {
        foreach($this->tables as $table)
        {
            $method  = 'migration_' . $table;
            $array[] = $this->$method();
        }

        return $array;
    }

    private function migration_a()
    {
        return 'a';
    }

    private function migration_b()
    {
        return 'b';
    }

    private function migration_n()
    {
        return 'n';
    }
}
```

El problema es que si no existe el método, lanza un error. El cual podríamos controlar mediante:

```
class MyClass2
{
    /**
     * La segunda opción para evitar errores
     * Comprobar que el método lamado existe mediante getMethod()
     */
    public function runMigrations2()
    {
        foreach($this->tables as $table)
        {
            $method  = 'migration_' . $table;
            $array[] = $this->getMethod($method);
        }

        return $array;
    }

    private function getMethod($method)
    {
        if(method_exists($this, $method)):
            return $this->$method();
        else:
            return null;
        endif;
    }
}
```

Si se decide seguir con la práctica de usar `call_user_func` una forma correcta sería así:

```
class MyClass3
{
    /**
     * El problema es igual que runMigrations1()
     * Si el método llamado no existe, lanza un error de tipo:
     * Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
     * class 'MyClass' does not have a method 'migration_z' in //...
     */
    public function runMigrations3()
    {
        foreach($this->tables as $table)
        {
            $method  = 'migration_' . $table;
            $array[] = call_user_func(array($this, $method));
        }

        return $array;
    }
}
```

Los errores, siempre que sean susceptibles de ocurrir, deben ser controlados para seguir con las buenas prácticas.

```
class MyClass4
{
    /**
     * Podemos solucionarlo contorlando el error
     */
    public function runMigrations4()
    {
        foreach($this->tables as $table)
        {
            $method  = 'migration_' . $table;
            $array[] = $this->getMethodCallUserFunc($method);
        }

        return $array;
    }

    private function getMethodCallUserFunc($method)
    {
        if(method_exists($this, $method)):
            return call_user_func(array($this, $method));
        else:
            return null;
        endif;
    }
}
```

Si haces un `var_dump()` sobre cualquiera de los `runMigrations` verás el resultado que lanza cada uno, a excepción de los que lanzan error por no encontrar el método `z` creado a modo error.

```
$instance = new MyClass1(); // 2,  3, 4
var_dump($instance->runMigrations1()); // 2,  3, 4
```

Dará un resultado así con los que tiene el control de error

```
  array (size=4)
    0 => string 'a' (length=1)
    1 => string 'b' (length=1)
    2 => string 'n' (length=1)
    3 => null
```

Comment: Si no he cometido ningún error al redactarlo, debería dar los resultados esperados. Espero que sirva.

Comment: Agradezco tu chorro, pero la respuesta es mas simple. Prefiero no matar moscas a cañonazos. Cuando hice la pregunta corregie el tema del array. Incluso antes de que publicaras, ya estaba corregido. (sic). En cuanto a lo demas, se trata de un codigo que no requiere verificacion de error, pues esta interno (private) y bastante controlado. Y como he dichio, no hace falta  usar call_user_func. Saludos.